# How to get the api name of the quick action which invoked the flow?

Tags: quickaction, pagereference

I am using a generic flow which can be invoked from multiple objects. In Flow, I have embedded the LWC Component, by using the Currentpagereference I am able to get the quick action name of the only some objects like opportunity etc and I am unable to get the quick action name which launched the flow for some objects like order and quote may be because of the url. The URL when the quick action launched from the opportunity looks like this:

```
Domainname/lightning/action/quick/Opportunity.quickactionapiname
```

But when i invoke the flow from order object the url turns out to be:

```
Domainname/lightning/r/Order/id/view
```

Currentpagereference code looks like this:

```
import { CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';
@wire(CurrentPageReference)
    getStateParameters(currentPageReference) {        
        if(currentPageReference.type === 'standard__quickAction') {
            this.quickActionAPIName = currentPageReference.attributes.apiName;
        }
        console.log(currentPageReference.type);
    }
```

Due to this, iam getting currentpagereference.type as standard__recordpage for order object and standard__quickAction for opprtunity object.

Is there any work around?

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just pass in the name of the quick action when launching the flow as a hard-coded value? Or are you really trying to get the object that the quick action was launched from? If the latter, you should be able to use `@api objectApiName;` to get that.

Comment: Thanks Rob. But I don't need the object name, I need to get the name of the quick action dynamically without hardcoding. Is there any way to get the quick action api name without hardcoding?